# Nerdtree vertical bar slightly off center

Tags: vim

As you can see in the photo, my *nerdtree* vertical line is somewhat *broken* looking and it is driving me crazy.

I want it to be totally flush. Does anyone know how to achieve this? I have been searching for hours now and havent come across anything yet.

[image: example of my nerdtree vertical bar]

Comment: Which OS and terminal are you using?

Comment: chrome OS pixelbook, ZSH

Answer (score 1):

i believe it has something to do with line wrapping being activated, but i'm not really sure. Try checking out my config [.vimrc](https://github.com/juanCortelezzi/Dotfiles/blob/master/.vimrc) might help you with your problem.

Also, it may help if you add a link to your config like i did, or post it below, for others to see in better detail whats wrong. And obviously, check if [Nerdtree's](https://github.com/preservim/nerdtree) Github page has some FAQ's or issues that may be helpful.

Comment: I ended up moving the tree to the right side. From there, the line break doesnt seem to be a problem.Thanks for your help.